# Did not obtain Aubery Mask after getting Phew!

Tags: payday-2

Played the Hotline Miami mission on V. Hard, and on day 2 I defused the bomb on the guy in the chair, unlocking the trophy "phew!", we went on to complete the mission. However there's still no Aubery mask in my mask collection.

Do I need to find it in a card after getting the achievement or am I missing something else?

I should mention that I am playing on PS4 Crimewave Edition EU Disk Version.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just got the Walk Faster trophy and then completed the mission. No Graham mask either.

Comment: From what I am reading (mostly from the payday subreddit), the Crimewave Edition made all masks that were previously achievement masks (with the exception of the four Difficulty Skull masks) card drops instead. Sadly, I am not in a position to even try to verify this myself.

Comment: That would explain a lot actually, I will spend 100m offshore on cards and let this forum know if I get one of those four in a card.

Answer (score 1):

The Crimewave Edition drops all masks (even the DW mask) as drops, instead of through achievements.